# PHP socket_write works first time, but

Tags: php, sockets

I am tying to write several messages (each message created dynamically) to a device through one socket created with PHP. The first message always goes through; but, subsequent messages do *not* go through. To help me debug, please let me know if there is a problem with this example:

```
        $socket= socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        socket_connect($socket, $ip, $port); 
        socket_write($socket, "message 1\r");
        socket_write($socket, "message 2\r");
```

Comment: what does `echo socket_strerror()` give you?

Comment: @pduersteler placed immediately after socket_write gives a '0' or socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) gives "Unknown error: 0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding carriage returns to the `socket_write($socket, "message 1\r\n");` to the end of the message? In many cases, when working with buffers and streams, that seems to do the trick.

Something else worth giving a shot:

```
//all suggestions rolled into one (including Chris' chr(0) - thanks for that one)
socket_write($socket, 'message 1'."\r\n".chr(0));
usleep(5);
socket_write($socket, 'Foobar'."\r\n".chr(0));
```

just giving that little bit of extra time to clear the buffer can do wonders.

**EDIT**

Just had another brain wave: have you tried using the optional length parameter, too?

```
socket_write($socket, 'message 1'."\r\n".chr(0),strlen('message 1'."\r\n".chr(0)));
```

Comment: I will try messing with usleep(5).  I am currently ending the messages with '\r'.  (I will edit to reflect the '\r')

Comment: @JohnR: ending with `\r` won't do, best to use either `\n` (UNIX) or `\r\n` (windows). `\r` is sort of windows-y but not quite there... so I strongly advise you to use `\r\n` :P

Comment: In addition to the line ending suggestion, the program on the other end might be waiting for a null byte terminated chunk. `$nullByte = chr(0);` That had me scratching my own head last week...

Comment: @chris , I'm not clear; should that be placed after the socket write line?

Comment: `socket_write($socket, "message 2\r\n$nullByte");` You may or may not need it, and it may or may not need to be sent along with the line ending characters. It depends on whats on the other end of the socket and how it works, but its easy to just try it.

Comment: Thanks @chris for getting back, it was worth a shot, but still no go.  I will keep trying.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem , Thanks! What worked for me was usleep(500000) . usleep is in microseconds, so that is half a second. I will shorten the duration some, but it fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance, I'll also keep this in mind since it's not unlikely I will run into similar problems next time I'm doing something similar ;). `usleep(500000);` does seem an awfully long time, I usually start off with 1000 and decrease in steps of 100 (just a suggestion)

Comment: Yeah it's ridiculously long, but it's late and I just needed to know it will work :) .  1000 seems like a good place to start and back off from there. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't work usleep(XXX) or char(0), nothing works for me, but same problem :'(

Comment: @Matrix: if you're calling `char(0)`, then that would indeed be a problem (the function is `chr`). If you are having the same problem, and this answer doesn't help, consider asking a new question, posting the actual code because the problem might be caused by something else. Downvoting a correct answer doesn't really help anyone

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes it's chr(0), mistake in message. I have my own question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539318/how-use-only-one-socket-to-send-many-requests-http-in-php, but I search others ideas too.

Comment: @Matrix: You're using `fsockopen`, this answer applies to `socket_create`. Naturally this answer won't work in your case. Looking at your question, I can't see you using `fread` on your socket. If you want to reuse a socket, you're going to have to manually create, read, manipulate and bind your sockets. `fsockopen` is something I've only ever seen used in a sort of _"fire and forget"_ way

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I test with socket_create too, nothing change... it's same behavior.